# Can I make an IDataReader ignore column length definitions?

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm working with a ProgressDB table that defines columns as strings of max length *x*, but in no way, shape, or form actually enforces this limitation;  I have discovered several cases where the column data is significantly larger than the column length as defined.  (It was an unpleasant shock to discover that was even possible).  It is conceivable that there may be a way to enforce these constraints on the database side, but that is not practical at this time for a multitude of reasons.

My application bombs in a rather spectacular way upon encountering a row with such illegal data.  I can catch the exception at the row read level, but what I'd really like to do is read the row and disregard the exception, as I am manipulating the string data and do not care about the length at all.

Is there a way to do this using the `IDataReader` interface?  These are large datasets and manipulating it in a `DataTable` is not a realistic solution.

**UPDATE** Here's an interesting (frustrating) thing: I tried to capture a bad `IDataReader.Read()` like so:

```
var reading = true;
do
{
    try
    {
        reading = r.Read();
        if (reading)
        {
            var columns = new string[columnCount - 1];
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (columnCount - 1); i++)
                {
                    columns[i] = Convert.ToString(r.GetValue(i));
                }
                writer.Write(string.Join(this.ColumnDelimiter, columns) + this.RowDelimiter);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("Exception dumping table {0}.  At the point of the error, the columns resembled:\r\n{1}\r\n\r\nThe exception was: {2}",
                    this.TableName, string.Join(this.ColumnDelimiter, columns.Select(c => c ?? string.Empty).ToArray()), ex.ToString()), ex);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error reading row.", ex);
    }

} while (reading);
```

...but when I ran this, the application puked with an uncaught exception:

```
2012-04-17 16:14:22,863 [1] ERROR GHM.ODBCSqlDump.Parser [(null)] - Error reading row.
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Column [ColumnName] in table [TableName] has value exceeding its max length or precision.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Read()
   at GHM.ODBCSqlDump.Parser.Execute(Stream streamOut)

Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLFetch(OdbcStatementHandle StatementHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.Fetch()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Read()
   at GHM.ODBCSqlDump.Parser.Execute(Stream streamOut)
   at GHM.DatabaseDump.Executor.ExecuteGroup(TransferGroup group)
   at GHM.DatabaseDump.Executor.Execute()
   at GHM.DatabaseDump.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

... my troubles increase at a faster pace than my solutions... sigh...

Comment: What are you using now (if not IDataReader), and how does it "bomb" exactly?

Comment: I am using IDataReader (OdbcDataReader) right now. On the `.Read()` where there is a malformed row, I get a `OdbcException` "Column [ColumnName] in table [TableName] has value exceeding its max length or precision."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is messy. Can you modify your SQL SELECT statement to perform a `SUBSTRING(1, n)` where `n` is the defined length of the field, on each of the text fields that might be causing the overflow? You  won't be able to get back all of the data in each field (which is bad data to begin with), but at least it might stop the exception.

Sorry, I'm not a ProgressDB guy, so I'm framing the solution in terms of T-SQL.

Comment: Hah! not very easily, but it might be possible... I'll look into that.

Comment: I'm trying to think about why the ODBC driver is checking the query results against the defined schema on the table, which seems odd to me that it is doing that. Also odd is the database allowing overflow values, but that is another matter. :)

Comment: I ended up doing exactly as you suggested.  It's rather ugly but it works.  My advice to everyone, if someone suggests using a Progress DB for anything, don't say a word, just walk right up to them and punch that person in the mouth as hard as you can.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs Progress does not natively support SQL, its native language is Progress 4GL (or ABL, as it is called today).  SQL supported is bolted on top of Progress.  "Support" for limits is there only because SQL is inflexible and needs it.  How to deal with your problem is covered in Progress Knowledge Base here: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P13348

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called width in the definition of the table in progress, where is defined the length for sql or odbc sources. This field has to be long enough to fit all the data. Otherwise you will end up getting that error.